# selecting where in multiple join tables

Tags: mysql

I have the logic worked out, just not sure how to best write this query.

the logic is

> we have a deal ID of 1
>   a deal is linked to multiple regions
>   a deal is linked to multiple interests
>   a user is linked to multiple regions
>   a user is linked to multiple interests
>   we want all users where....
>
> the user is linked to the same region as a deal
>
> userRegionLink url, dealRegionLink drl
>   url.regionId is in drl.regionId where drl.dealId = 1
>   the user is linked to the same interest as a deal
>   userInterestLink uil, dealInterestLink dil
>   uil.interestId is in dil.interestId where dil.dealId = 1
>   this would give us a list of the users
>   now we need to select distinct from the list so we only end up sending each user a single email

But I have no idea what the best way to write this query would be.

We are dealing with a few tables here

We have

`users` which has all the user Information in it `userId` and other columns not important

`userInterestLink` which has `userId` and `interestId`
`dealInterestLink` which has `dealId` and `interestId`

`userRegionLink` which has `userId` and `regionId`
`dealRegionLink` which has `dealId` and `regionId`

so what we are wanting in the end is all the user info which matches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I take RC's answer and modify it

```
SELECT u.userId, uil.interestId, url.regionId FROM users u 
  JOIN userInterestLink uil ON (uil.userId = u.userId) 
  JOIN userRegionLink url ON (url.userId = u.userId) 
WHERE interestId IN (
  SELECT DISTINCT interestId FROM dealInterestLink WHERE dealId = 1
) AND regionId IN (
  SELECT DISTINCT regionId FROM dealRegionLink WHERE dealId = 1
)
```

as there is no need for `LEFT JOIN` if I exclude the `NULL` rows afterwards.

A more "symmetric" version without subqueries and with `USING` would be

```
SELECT u.userId, uil.interestId, url.regionId FROM users u 
  JOIN userInterestLink uil USING (userId)
  JOIN userRegionLink url USING (userId)
  JOIN dealInterestLink dil USING (interestId)
  JOIN dealRegionLink drl USING (regionId, dealId)
WHERE dealId = 1
```

Untested as well.

Comment: Tested using my Dummy Data. Worked OK.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
SELECT u.userId, uil.interestId, url.regionId FROM users u 
  LEFT JOIN userInterestLink uil ON (uil.userId = u.userId) 
  LEFT JOIN userRegionLink url ON (url.userId = u.userId) 
WHERE uil.interestId IS NOT NULL AND uil.interestId IN (
  SELECT DISTINCT interestId FROM dealInterestLink WHERE dealId = 1
) AND url.regionId IS NOT NULL AND url.regionId IN (
  SELECT DISTINCT regionId FROM dealRegionLink WHERE dealId = 1
)
```

? If result is OK, you can then `SELECT DISTINCT u.userId FROM users u -- ...`

(not tested)

Comment: Tested this with my dummy data - Works OK. (Just need to use that `DISTINCT` or `GROUP BY` to return one row per User.)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT `u`.*
  FROM `users` AS `u`
  JOIN `userRegionLink` `userReg` USING ( `userId` )
  JOIN `userInterestLink` `userInt` USING ( `userId` )
  JOIN `dealInterestLink` `dealInt` USING ( `interestId` )
  JOIN `dealRegionLink` `dealReg` USING ( `regionId` )
  JOIN `deal` `d` ON ( `dealInt`.`dealId` && `dealReg`.`dealId` && `d`.`dealId` = 1 )
GROUP BY `u`.`userId`
```

Tested locally using dummy data and presumed schema. Worked OK.